# Casting from Non-generic base class to Generic Sub class

Tags: java, generics

I have non-generic parent class.

```
public class FilterCondition {

    private String key;

    private String value;

    private String  condition;
}
```

And I have a generic subclass.

```
public class FilterJoinCondition<P,S> extends FilterCondition {
    public FilterJoinCondition(String key, String value, String condition) {
        super(key, value, condition);
    }

    private Class primaryEntity;

    private Class secondaryEntity;

    private String mappedBy;
}
```

I store all the `FilterCondition` in a `List` and pass to a method where I need the types passed to the `FilterJoinCondition`

```
if (condition instanceof FilterJoinCondition) {
     FilterJoinCondition<P,S>  joinCondition = (FilterJoinCondition) condition;
}
```

I know this is not correct (above code).

How could I cast `FilterCondition` without knowing the types (P,S) ?

Comment: Is `primaryEntity` a `Class<P>` and `secondaryEntity` a `Class<S>`? If so, you could use those to check P and S

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `?` placeholder. Obviously you won't be able to do things with the new `joinCondition`, that requires knowledge of the specific Types. But all the general stuff you can do just fine.

```
public class FilterJoinCondition<P,S> extends FilterCondition {

    private Class primaryEntity;

    private Class secondaryEntity;

    private String mappedBy;
    
    public FilterJoinCondition(String key, String value, String condition) {
        super(key, value, condition);
    }
    
    public void doStuff(P param) {
        System.out.println(param.getClass());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FilterCondition condition = new FilterJoinCondition<>("foo", "bar", "baz");
        
        if (condition instanceof FilterJoinCondition) {
             FilterJoinCondition<?,?>  joinCondition = (FilterJoinCondition) condition;
             joinCondition.doStuff(new String()); //illegal, you do not know P!
        }
    }
}
```